# Session retention after login on iOS app and Devise with Rails

Tags: ios, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I'm building an iOS app with Rails on the back-end.

The Rails application uses Devise for authentication and I want to use the same service for the authentication on the iOS app. Is there any way that after authenticating, keeping the session even after the app restarts, so that it goes straight to the content of the app instead of the login screen?

I've looked around, but haven't found a clear answer.

Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to extend the existing devise models and controllers to also handle a token based authentication system. Based on the request type `html` or `json`, the app can choose to authenticate a user either by the authentication token and email or a combination of `username/email` and password. 
The authentication token could could be saved on the client side and reset only when the user logs out. 
I was recently working on the same problem and found these sources to be extremely useful.

1. https://gist.github.com/josevalim/fb706b1e933ef01e4fb6
2. http://www.soryy.com/blog/2014/apis-with-devise/
3. https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth